# How can I create table with a changing border color on row hover?

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I have a table with seven columns, and when mouseover any row, I want to show First LEFT column border green and Last RIGHT column border green, how can write that code in PHP or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS it can be done like so:

```
tr:hover td:first-child{
    border-left-color:green;
}
tr:hover td:last-child{
    border-right-color:red;
}
```

See [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtokunk5/)